# How to insert multiple tables in a word document

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

This may seem as a duplicate, but none of the other solutions worked for me.
I want to insert tables in a document, one after another, not one inside the first cell of the previous table.

Here's my code. The stupid amount of commented lines is me being desperate.

```
Dim bmMain As Bookmark = AnexaDoc.Bookmarks("Content")
'Dim tbRanges As New List(Of Range)
Dim tbRange As Range = bmMain.Range
tbRange.InsertParagraphAfter()
For i = 0 To Imobile.Count - 1

    tabelSuprafata = AnexaDoc.Tables.Add(tbRange.Next(WdUnits.wdParagraph), Imobile(i).Geometry.NumberOfVertices + 1, 3)

    With tabelSuprafata
        .Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Nr."
        .Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "Nord"
        .Cell(1, 3).Range.Text = "Est"
        .ApplyStyleHeadingRows = True
        For r = 2 To .Rows.Count
            .Cell(r, 1).Range.Text = (r - 1).ToString
            .Cell(r, 2).Range.Text = Me.Imobile(i).Geometry.GetPoint2dAt(r - 2).Y.ToString
            .Cell(r, 3).Range.Text = Me.Imobile(i).Geometry.GetPoint2dAt(r - 2).X.ToString
        Next
    End With
    tabelSuprafata.Borders.InsideLineStyle = WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle
    tabelSuprafata.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle
    'tabelSuprafata.Range.Collapse(Direction:=WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
    'tabelSuprafata.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()
    'tbRange.InsertParagraphAfter()
    'tabelSuprafata.Range.Collapse(Direction:=WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
    'tabelSuprafata.Range.Select()
    tbRange.Collapse(Direction:=WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
    tbRange.InsertParagraphAfter()
    tbRange.Collapse(Direction:=WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
    'tbRange.Select()
    'tbRange.EndOf(WdUnits.wdTable, WdMovementType.wdMove)
    'tbRange.EndOf(WdUnits.wdParagraph, WdMovementType.wdMove)

    'tbRange = tbRange.Next(WdUnits.wdParagraph)

Next
```

Update1: tbRange.InsertBreak() kind of works, if I ignore the empy page inserted for each break.
The code above actually inserts the table in the second cell, this is the most I could do.

Comment: You have to move your cursor location outside of the first table, before creating your next one.

Comment: ...not necessary move cursor but you need to set range where you table is located to the right after table you created in previous loop. Can you cope with that on your own?

Comment: Thank you for both of your answers, but I already knew that the cursor is for whatever reason inside of the last table. I suppose I cannot cope with that on my own, if I could I wouldn't have asked. I know this may seem trivial(and it probably is), but I tried various things for the last 10 hours straight and nothing worked. I simply can't imagine what incantation I must use to achieve such a simple task.